# Pyinstaller cannot import PdfReader

Tags: for-loop, command, pyinstaller

My machine is Win7/10 64bits. The python program runs without errors. I'm using Pyinstaller and have a module that has several hidden "submodules". There is no problem so far, but the submodul PdfReader gives error with --hidden-import PdFReader.
Error: cannot import PdfReader from PyPDF2.

In source code:

import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader,PdfWriter

The routine to generate the exe is as follows:
Pyinstaller --hidden-import PyPDF2 --hidden-import PdfReader  --onefile PART_2.py

All programs are installed using pip.
Question: how to import PdfReader into the one exe-File?